# CancellationToken not Triggering when using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, azure-web-app-service, cancellation-token

I know questions like this have been asked a dozen of times here, but none of the provided answers solved my particular problem. So I'm giving it another try by asking a question myself.

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core web application running on regular `net461` (also tried `net48`), where I defined an HTTP endpoint like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("query/{queryName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Call(string queryName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  await Task.Delay(5_000, cancellationToken);
  ...
}
```

As the title already states, I can't make the `cancellationToken` trigger a `TaskCanceledException` upon initiating a refresh on browser side, while the initial request is still being processed (Chrome devtools displays these events as cancelled requests). The only way I can make it work, is by selecting "Project" in Visual Studio's Debug settings (see screenshot below), which I guess, makes the whole application run in Kestrel only - without any reverse proxy in front.

[image]

I came across various post that claimed this issue would be solved with ASP.NET Core 2.2, where in-process hosting should work in combination with `CancellationToken`. So I updated all my nuget packages, but unfortunately with no effect, the error still persists. Yes, locally I'm debugging using IIS Express and I'm not sure how exactly this differs from a regular IIS setup, but I'm also running this app on Azure, where the whole process looks like it was running in-process, because there is only a single process running (see screenshot below).

[image]

This is an extract from my csproj with the AspNetCore packages I installed:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS" Version="2.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I also played around with the Program.cs, because I suspect this might be another potential source of error. I Tried to use the `UseIIS()` extension method only to enforce in-process hosting, but also no visible effect with regard to `CancellationToken`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            //.UseKestrel()
            .UseIIS()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            //.UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

**My Questions:**

1. Does `CancellationToken` only work with `netcoreapp2.x` (or higher) as target framework?
2. Is this a configuration issue (Program.cs, Startup.cs, csproj, etc)?
3. Can I run this app on an Azure Web App Service on Windows while using Kestrel only? If yes, how do I configure this?
4. Is there anything else that I might have missed to make this work?

Comment: Bottom line is you can't *depend* on `CancellationToken` being triggered. As far as details go, IIRC .NET Framework had a nasty race condition that could cause a crash, so they turned off support for CT-reported loss of connections. I believe that has been fixed in .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: It turned out that the Azure App Service is using a level 7 load balancer, which does NOT forward connection-close events to the web app. So it does not matter whether you use a Kestrel or in-process hosted web app on IIS, your app will never get notified.

The obvious solution is to handle such events yourself on application level. Either by setting a `KeepAliveInterval` (WebSockets) or by directly subscribing to the connection-closed event using SignalR.

Comment: I wanted to say thank you for posting this; we've been pulling our hair out trying to understand why this works locally, but not in Azure. This post is 4 years old, have you found a better work around for this? We found your original GitHub issue here which has since been closed: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20229

Comment: No, I ended up monitoring the web client's status via a parallel websocket connection to determine when request processing should be canceled. However, it appears to be possible to use native cancelation tokens with Azure Functions now. If I'm not mistaken Functions uses the same host as any ASP.NET Core application, so it should be possible to apply the same configuration to the ASP.NET Core host. Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: RE:Azure Functions; We saw the same thing and had the same thoughts. We opened a new support case and will update this post if we ever hear back.